# Check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE order_id = 2' at line 1

Tags: sql, mariadb, syntax-error

Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE order_id = 2' at line 1

I get this error when I'm trying to get data after joining orders, users and products table

**Full query:**

```
SELECT O.order_id,
       U.username,
       P.product_name
FROM orders O
INNER JOIN users U ON O.user_id = U.user_id
INNER JOIN products P ON O.product_id = P.product_id
ORDER BY O.order_id
WHERE O.order_id = ${id}
```

**Expected output:**

```
        {
            "order_id": 1,
            "username": "userrrr",
            "product_name": "Test Product"
        },
        {
            "order_id": 2,
            "username": "test04",
            "product_name": "Product product"
        }
```

Comment: you have added where condition after orderBy clause

Comment: Looks like you didn't check the manual (as suggested by the error message): https://mariadb.com/kb/en/select/ clearly lists WHERE clause before ORDER BY

Answer (score 1):

The `where` clause should come before the `order by` clause, not after it:

```sql
SELECT     orders.order_id, users.username, products.product_name 
FROM       orders
INNER JOIN users ON orders.user_id = users.user_id
INNER JOIN products ON orders.product_id = products.product_id
WHERE      order_id = ${id}
ORDER BY   orders.order_id
```